# During the test i am gettitng following error -> WrongTypeOfReturnValue

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, mockito

```
//class which is mocked
data class Class (

    val varaibles: kotlin.collections.List<anotherExampleClass>? = null,

)

    @Nested
    inner class Test{
        @Test
        fun `test is passed`() {
            `when`(mockClass.varaibles?.find{variable -> variable.name!!.contains("name")}?.value).thenReturn("testName")

        }

    }
```

I am getting error like "String cannot be returned by getMethod() getMethod() should return List
"
I tried the following one  -> `` doReturn("testName").`when`(mockClass).variables?.find {find{variable -> variable.name!!.contains("name")}?.value ``
But still getting the same error.
Why i am getting this error and how may I fix it?

Comment: Can you tell us the type of `variables` in mockClass please?

Comment: I added it in the question

Comment: It's the "anotherExampleClass" I need to know. It's most likely that .value on "AnotherExampleClass" is not a string type?

Comment: it is String -> val `value`: kotlin.String? = null

Comment: I'm not very familiar with this syntax, but the way you mock seems strange. Since it's "mockClass" which is mocked, the way to mock should be `when(mockClass.variable).thenReturn(aListOfData)` and the `aListOfData` should contain the data that, when queried with `.find` would allow you to do what you do here (contains one element with .name equal to "name" and .value equal to "testName")

Comment: I got your point, I think you are right, I will try as You suggested and I will let you know. Thanks

Comment: Thanks again it works, the way how I did, usually no one do like that?

Comment: No and I think it can't work because only mockClass is mocked, so when you call mockClass.variables it's a default value set by Mockito which is probably an empty list.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in comment, the way you mock can't work.

Since only `mockClass` is mocked, you have to tell Mockito what's returned from `mockClass.varaibles`:

`when(mockClass.varaibles).thenReturn(aListOfData)` where `aListOfData` is a list containing one element like { name: "name", value: "testName" }, so that when, in your code, the `.find` method is called, it returns what you need